# com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: 102 when attaching

Tags: java, exception, virtual-machine

Stack Trace:

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: 102
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:109)
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:120)
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:148)
    at Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

Code:

```
try {
            attach.loadAgent(agent.getAbsolutePath() , "1");
            System.out.println("Agent was loaded.");
        } catch (AgentLoadException e) {
            System.err.println("Agent failed to load: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AgentInitializationException e) {
            System.err.println("Agent loaded, but failed to initialize: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Trying to attach an agent to a VM
I get AgentLoadException:102
102 upon looking up is ATTACH_ERROR_STARTFAIL
Any ideas on how can I solve it?
thanks.